# C++ many readers single writer mutex starvation

Tags: c++, mutex

I am making something with many readers all accessing a vector but a single writer that will randomly interject to update the vector. Is there a simple way for the readers to yield to the writer?

Apparently GCC and others use POSIX threads which favor readers while Windows tries to be fair for all. I want something that lets the writer get top priority over readers (I'm not worried about reader starvation, the writer is very intermittent).

My understanding is that a conditional variable can be used, but wouldn't the writer have to specifically let in each reader? I want the writer to be mostly dormant.

I am trying to do something like this (not exactly correct c++):

```
Writer:
  while(true){
     sleep(long time);
     writer_waiting = true; //<- this is the critical part I don't know how to implement
     mutex.lock();
     writer_waiting = false;
     // Party         
     mutex.unlock();
  }

Readers:
   while(true){
     wait(writer_waiting);
     mutex.lock_shared();
     // Party
     mutex.unlock_shared();
   }
```

Comment: Starvation isn't usually a problem unless the lock is highly contended.  Is there something you can do to reduce the frequency at which readers need to acquire the lock, and/or the duration of time for which they hold the lock?

Comment: Is that typically the solution? Maybe I don't have a starvation problem, I'm very new to c++ and multithreading in general, but the execution does look like starvation. It just would fit well with how I conceptualize my program if I could have it perform the way I described.

Comment: Want writer get top priority and mostly dormant?Is it conflict?

Comment: If you post a compilable example that reproduces the problem, then I (and other people) can try it out for ourselves and see what is actually going on and therefore what solutions might help.  With pseudocode, all we can do is speculate; so my speculation is that starvation is likely just the most visible symptom of another problem, such as busy-waiting by the reader-threads.

Comment: Concerning the `Readers:`: Shouldn't it be `wait(!writer_waiting);`? And, `writer_waiting` is a `std::atomic`?

Comment: Concerning `wait(!writer_waiting);`: Maybe, I took the `wait()` to literally as a [std::condition_variable::wait](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) which waits until the condition becomes `true`... ;-)

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. This has been a learning experience for me. I think the best way to do what I proposed is to set an atomic boolean that can be used by the writer to flag readers that it is waiting to write, whereupon the readers will wait on a conditional variable that the writer controls (without holding a shared lock). Ultimately the readers will all queue up waiting on the writer to do its thing - after which the writer will trigger the conditional variable to let all the readers read.
That said, it appears as though other issues likely were the culprit.